# Delete every element whose index satisfies condition; list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, iteration

I'm doing an exercise where a function takes a list and an integer `n` and deletes every element if its index `i` satisfies `(i+1)%n==0`. Here's what I've come up with:

```
def f(lst, n):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if (i+1)%n==0:  
            del lst[i]
```

However, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pop.py", line 4, in f
    del lst[i]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

The index pointer `i` doesn't seem to be able to run out of range? What causes this to happen?

Comment: Please provide example data for clarity and testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Think about what happens when you remove a items from a list. The length of this list changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What data set are you using?
Depending on the numbers in your data set, the problem is that you're deleting objects from your list, creating a conflict when you ask for a specific index in that list.

```
ex_list = [2, 5, 12]
print range(len(ex_list))

output [0, 1, 2]
```

So lets say the first item doesn't pass your test and gets deleted. Now oyur list looks like this:

```
ex_list
>>>[5, 12]
```

The problem is that your next i in your for loop will be 1 but now:

```
ex_list[1]
>>>12
```

and ultimately:

```
ex_list[2]
>>>IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that when you are deleting an element from a list, your list size is changing.

You don't have to iterate over the list to find the the indexes that is divisible by n.
for e.g.  if list_length = 8 and n = 2, then we know the element#[2,4,6,8] = index[1,3,5,7] have to deleted. You can just create a filter here or list comprehension like this will also do-

```
new_list = [old_list[i] for i in range(len(old_list_length)) if (i+1) % n == 0]
old_list = new_list
```

**Note** :- You can note iterate over a list, where a element have been deleted, since the original element you like to delete, will now have different index. Going with the example in the start of answer:-
lets say you have deleted `element#2(index = 1)`, Now subsequent `element#4,#8` will now become `element #3, #7`, so now you cannot track the original elements you wanted to remove the list.